# "afterRender threw an error in 'lightning:clickToDial' [a.replace is not a function]" when dynamically displaying lightning:clickToDial

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

I have a VisualForce page with a script to dynamically display a `lightning:clickToDial` component. However, when the page is loaded I receive the following error message:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. afterRender
>   threw an error in 'lightning:clickToDial' [a.replace is not a
>   function] Failing descriptor: {lightning:clickToDial}

Screenshot:
[image]

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:includeLightning />
<script>
        $Lightning.use("c:ClickToDialApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:ClickToDial",
          { phone : 11231231234},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
</script>

<div id="lightning" /> 
</apex:page>
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="phone" type="Integer"/>
    TESTING: <lightning:clickToDial value="{!v.phone}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Lightning Dependency App:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:ClickToDial"/>
</aura:application>
```

Any information on what might be causing this error would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The Lightning component parameter value required quotes:

```
{ phone : "11231231234"}
```